# Negative representation of a binary number

Tags: computer-science, binary, binary-operations

I saw online that if you want to convert a binary number to a negative binary number, you add 1.However, I don't understand why you do that.In a forum I saw someone explaining the following:

> ```
> A little rule that I use when I need to represent negative numbers in binary is
> ~i = -i-1.
> That is, the bitwise inversion of "i" is equivalent to negative "i" less one.
> In your example, you're looking for the binary representation of -192. Since -192 = -191-1, the following statement is true:
> ~191 = -192.
> ```

Unfortunately, I don't understand this explanation.I went on further to understand the bit wise inversion of binary and I did understand that: it's only changing 1 into 0 and o into 1. Then I saw the following explanation from Microsoft:

```
~5 == 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111010 == -6 in decimal.
```

How do  you really get -6 from ~5?How that gives you negative -6. Isn't 6 is 110?And if you add 1 to make it negative, shouldn't it be 111?Can someone please explain?

Comment: This is no mathematics question. This is about the two's / one's complement representation of a binary number. Btw, you must also take the bitlength of the variables into account. Here, we assume that we're dealing with `int32` (32-bit wide) numbers, and so if $5 = (101)_2$, then $~5 = ( \underbrace{1...1}_{32-3\text{ ones}}010)_2$.

Comment: The $\LaTeX$ swallowed the `~` there, sorry. The bitwise inverse of $5$ is then equal to that on the right. And it's $32-3 = 29$ ones because the number is 32 bits wide, meaning $5 = (00000000 \;00000000\;00000000\;00000101)_2$  (this saved in memory in 4 bytes). Not only the 3 bits $101$ are inverted on the right, but also the $29$ bits (all $0$) are inverted. You should start reading into (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) or (http://www.cs.uwm.edu/~cs151/Bacon/Lecture/HTML/ch03s09.html)

Comment: I now understand it's because of 32 bits.What I don't understand is why you subtract 1.Why the bitwise inversion of "i" is equivalent to negative "i" less one.

Comment: That's because of the the two's compliment. If the left-most bit is $1$, this says that the saved number is negative. Taking the two's compliment negates the sign of a number $a$ and is equivlent to computing $~a + 1$. Therefore $-a = ~a + 1$. Then $-a - 1 = ~a$. Why the two's compliment works that way is what you should in the links above or additional googling (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lC5ckH5ODL4).

Answer (score 2):

To find the negative of a number $a$ you need to find a number $b$ that, when added to $a$, gives zero.

In binary this is done using the 2's complement method. The 2's complement method goes as follows: invert all bits and add $1$.

Why does it work?

Let's take a number $0101$. Inverting it gives $1010$. Adding These two numbers gives us $1111$. Actually, for any $n$ the following is true:

$n+\overline{n}= 1...1111$

Now adding a $1$ will make the $1...1111$ overflow and it will turn into $0...0000$.

Notice the overflow: In "real" mathematics the answer would be $1000...000$, but in computer arithmetic there is only a finite amount of bits to represent numbers. So therefore the answer is $0...000$ with a carry out of $1$.

So:

$n+\overline{n}+1=0 \iff \overline{n}+1=-n$

Comment: Good, but I would specify you're specifically talking about computer arithmetic, i.e. arithmetic mod $2^n$.

Comment: Yep, computer arithmetic. In "real" maths there isn't an overflow.

Answer (score 2):

"How do you really get -6 from ~5?How that gives you negative -6. Isn't 6 is 110?And if you add 1 to make it negative, shouldn't it be 111?Can someone please explain?"

You invert 5 and add a one. You don't get -6 by simply adding a one to 6. Gilianzz' answer explains it the best.